# Mongodb Multi tenant design for time series data

Tags: mongodb, database-design, time-series, iot

I am developing an IOT application for time series data. The application will be provided as SaaS for multi tenants. 
I have decided to go fir mongodb as my database. What should be the design for multi tenant time series data?

Should i go for different document per client or different database per client?  Because i read that different collection per client is considered bad design in MongoDb.

Answer (score 0):

For multi tenant consider separate database for each tenant. This adds privacy to the tenant data.